# Best formula/method to extract a standard set of numbers from a string?

Tags: excel, string, text

I have the following strings from which I need to extract 6 digit numbers. Since these strings are generated by another software, they occur interchangeably and I cannot control it. Is there any one method that would extract both 6-digit numbers from each of these strings?

Branch '100235 to 100236 Ckt 1' specified in table 'East Contingency' for record with primary key = 21733 was not found in branch or transformer data.

Loadflow branch ID '256574_701027_1' defined in supplemental branch table was not found in branch or transformer input.

Transmission element from bus number 135415 to bus number 157062 circuit ID = 1 defined for corridor  'IESO-NYISO' was not found in input data

I don't know VBA, but I can learn it if it means I can get the 6 digit numbers using a single method.
thanks

I have been using LEFT(), RIGHT() & MID() previously, but it means manually applying the appropriate formula for individual string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Microsoft 365, you can use this formula:

```
=LET(arr,TEXTSPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"'"," "),"_"," ")," "),
FILTER(arr,ISNUMBER(-arr)*(LEN(arr)=6)))
```

Thanks to @TomSharpe for this shorter version, using an array constant within `TEXTSPLIT` to add on possible delimiters.

```
=LET(arr,TEXTSPLIT(A1,{"_"," ",","," ","'"}),FILTER(arr,(LEN(arr)=6)*ISNUMBER(-arr)))
```

***Data***
[image]

***Output***
[image]

Comment: This set-up would require additional substitutions for each non-spacing character found next to the desired extraction, if I'm not mistaken? Also, note that, by not explicitly checking each individual character for numericalness, it would give false positives for cases such as 'Branch Mar-12 not found' (at least for English-language versions of Excel).

Comment: According to docs you can also use textsplit like this TEXTSPLIT(A1,{"'","_"," "}) if you know what the delimiters are

Comment: @TomSharpe Thanks for showing me something new (to me). Makes for a more compact formula.

Comment: @JosWoolley You are correct on both counts. Although @TomSharpe pointed me to the fact that one can use and array constant in `TEXTSPLIT` to accomplish same thing as I was doing with multiple substitutions.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is:

`=LET(ζ,MID(A1,SEQUENCE(,LEN(A1)-5),6),ξ,MID(ζ,SEQUENCE(6),1),FILTER(ζ,MMULT(SEQUENCE(,6,,0),1-ISERR(0+ξ))=6))`

Comment: NIcely done where I probably would have used VBA and regular expressions to deal that that sort of variability.

Comment: thank you! I will need to sit down and understand this one. havent used LET before

Answer (score 1):

A couple more suggestions (if you need them):

(1) Replacing all non-digit characters with a space then splitting the resulting string:

```
=LET(numbers,TEXTSPLIT(TRIM(REDUCE("",MID(A1,SEQUENCE(1,LEN(A1)),1),LAMBDA(a,c,IF(is.digit(c),a&c,a&" "))))," "),FILTER(numbers,LEN(numbers)=6))
```

Here I've defined a function is.digit as

```
=LAMBDA(c, IF(c = "", FALSE, AND(CODE(c) > 47, CODE(c) < 58)))
```

(tl;dr I quite like doing it this way because it hides the implementation details of is.digit and creates a rudimentary form of encapsulation)

(2) A UDF - based on the example [here](https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/regex/) and called as

```
=RegexTest(A1)
```

---

```
Option Explicit

Function RegexTest(s As String) As Double()

    Dim regexOne As Object
    Dim theNumbers As Object
    Dim Number As Object
    Dim result() As Double
    Dim i As Integer
    
    Set regexOne = New RegExp
    
    ' Not sure how you would extract numbers of length 6 only, so extract all numbers...
    
    regexOne.Pattern = "\d+"
    regexOne.Global = True
    regexOne.IgnoreCase = True
    
    Set theNumbers = regexOne.Execute(s)
    
    i = 1
    
    For Each Number In theNumbers
    
    '...Check the length of each number here
    
        If Len(Number) = 6 Then
            ReDim Preserve result(1 To i)
            result(i) = CDbl(Number)
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next
    
    RegexTest = result

End Function
```

*Note* - if you wanted to preserve leading zeroes you would need to omit the Cdbl() and return the numbers as strings. Returns an error if no 6-digit numbers are found.

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated. great starting point for me as I haven't used VBA before (did a bit of regex in python sometime ago)